# ASM Language: Factorial Algorithm Error?

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

I can't seem to find where I am wrong in my algorithm, my specific problem is that i seem to print the same value for all integer inputted in the console: here is my code

```
main:

li $v0, 5
syscall
jal factorial
li $v0, 10
syscall

factorial:
    ###preamble###
    subu $sp, $sp, 32
    sw $ra, 28($sp)
    sw $fp, 24($sp)
    addu $fp, $sp, 32
    sw $a0, 20($fp)
    ###preamble###

    lw $v0, 20($fp)
    bgtz $v0, multiply
    li $v0, 1
    j end

multiply:
    lw $v1, 20($fp)
    subu $v0, $v1, 1
    move $a0, $v0
    jal factorial

    lw $v1, 20($fp)
    li $t3, 0
    li $t2, 1
    b multi

    multi:
        beq $t2, $v0, endLOOP
        add $t3, $t3, $v1
        add $t2, $t2, 1
        b multi

    endLOOP:
        move $v0, $t3

end:
    lw $ra, 28($sp)
    lw $fp, 24($sp)
    addu $sp, $sp, 32
    move $a0, $v0
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    jr $ra
```

in this code i always seem to print a value of 10 while here in my second code, i always get an 11

```
main:

li $v0, 5
syscall 
jal factorial
li $v0, 10
syscall

factorial:
    ###preamble###
    subu $sp, $sp, 32
    sw $ra, 28($sp)
    sw $a0, 24($sp)
    li $v0, 1
    ble $a0, $zero, end
    b multiply
    ###preamble###

multiply:
    addi $a0, $a0, -1
    jal factorial
    lw $a0, 24($sp)
    b multi
    multi:
        beq $t2, $v0, endLOOP
        add $t3, $t3, $a0
        add $t2, $t2, 1
        b multi

    endLOOP:
        move $v0, $t3

end:
    lw $ra, 28($sp)
    addu $sp, $sp, 32
    move $a0, $v0
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    jr $ra
```

also, please note that we are not allowed to use the mult function so please dont ask why i am not using it. Thank you for your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of problems with your code:

> `li $v0, 5`
>   `syscall`
>   `jal factorial`

`syscall` 5 (`read_int`) will return the value in `$v0`, so when you enter `factorial` for the first time you'll have the argument in `$v0`. You could fix that by moving the value to `$a0` before the `jal`.

---

> `li $v0, 1`
>     `syscall`
>     `jr $ra`

Wouldn't this print make more sense outside of the factorial function? Since `$v0` is supposed to hold the function's return value, consider what will happen when you return from `factorial(2)` to `factorial(3)` and you've overwritten `$v0` with the value 1.

Comment: i got the first part of your answer for my question, but on the second one, i don't quite get it. But to make things much easier for me and for you as well, i'll just ask on how can i print the final value of the factorial in the console? Im not so sure on how to do it

Comment: _"the second one, i don't quite get it"_: I'm saying that you're overwriting the return value with the value 1, so that as you work your way back "out" through the recursion chain, `factorial(n)` will always get the value 1 from `factorial(n-1)` no matter what `n` is. I suggest that you move the print to after the _first_ call to `factorial` (i.e. right before the `exit` `syscall`). (I'm talking about your first implementation now, I didn't look at the second version)

Comment: Oh I see. The program is working fine now. Thank you for your help! :D